# Envio de datos a un Api

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api

Tengo dos metodos de tipo Post Pero lo que no se es como diferenciar un metodo del otro en la peticion de tipo Post.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ExpedienteDto Post(ExpedienteDto dto)
    {
        return ProcesosService.CrearExpediente(dto);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public NumeroExpediente GuardarNumeroConsuta(NumeroExpediente numero, string IdUsuario)
    {
        Console.Write(numero.ToString());
        return ProcesosService.GuardarNumeroConsuta(numero, IdUsuario);
    }
```

Como hago para diferenciar eso en esta parte para que cuando mande la peticion valla al metodo que debe ser que en este caso es el segundo en el codigo.

Comment: Te referis a la ruta?

Comment: ¿Si como lo hago? es que soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Va a variar según como tengas configuradas las rutas, por defecto, el acceso sería `/NombreController/NombreDelMétodo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el atributo `[Route]`

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("OtroNombreGuardarNumeroConsulta")]
    public NumeroExpediente GuardarNumeroConsuta(NumeroExpediente numero, string IdUsuario)
    {
        Console.Write(numero.ToString());
        return ProcesosService.GuardarNumeroConsuta(numero, IdUsuario);
    }
```

Para poder combinar tanto el routing por defecto {Controller}/{Action}/{id} con el Route de atributo tienes que agregar `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` en el metodo RegisterRoutes:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Menu", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```